# Update Specific row textarea and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on Simple Admin Panel,
The method i am working on is to select the data from database and put it into textarea and behind the textarea update button,
when i update the textarea click update to execute query to update the table
but when i click update at the first row for example it execute the third row only even if i clicked the first row update button " picture attached "

```
        <?php
include 'config.php';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"type="text/css">';

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM English");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<form action='' method='post'>";
    echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><textarea rows='1' cols='1' name='txtid' readonly style='overflow:auto;resize:none'>" . $row['ID'] . "</textarea></td>";
                echo "<td><textarea rows='4' cols='50' name='txtarea'>" . $row['Content'] . "</textarea></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='submit' name='button' value='Update!'/></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
  }
          echo "</table>";
          echo "</form>";

    if(isset($_POST['button'])){
    $textarea =$_POST['txtarea'];
    $id = $_POST['txtid'];
    $sql = "UPDATE English SET Content='".$textarea."' WHERE ID='".$id."'";
    echo $textarea; echo $id;
    mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
                   }

mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM8RC.png)

Comment: Did you check in console, each table row id are different are not?

Comment: Add a hidden input field with the `id` as value and use that in your `WHERE ID='".$id."'"`

Comment: Some years ago, we finally deprecated this insecure API. So what's it doing here?

Comment: Each row id are different, but it's only catch last result

Comment: If i click any button it act as i clicked the last button all buttons have the same action and variable looks fixed

Answer (score 0):

Well,
Changed the location for closing braces
to be after

```
  echo "</table>";
  echo "</form>";
```

it fixed the problem